# How to add two touching toolbar items to NSToolbar

Tags: macos, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I want to add two touching items, such as a forward and back button, to `NSToolbar`, like so:

[image]

`NSToolbar` seems to add horizontal margins by default, for each item, like this:

[image]

I checked out the XIB source code under the `toolbarItem` node, and there is no property/attribute that would provide a margin or padding.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would an `NSSegmentedControl` work?

Comment: That is a possibility, if it is possible to turn off borders for the control, so that only the button borders are showing. I'll give that a try tonight, thanks!

Comment: @NSGod That didn't do the trick. The `NSSegmentedControl` shows its own border, and doesn't allow me to set an `NSView` for a segment--only images or labels.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do use `NSSegmentedControl` for this which allows me to use my own images, labels, set custom actions, use a toggle, set a menu, etc. If this type of toolbar item works for you:

[image: segmented control toolbar items]

then you can see how I build these items in IB & code in this project (note that the AppDelegate class is the `delegate` for the `NSToolbar`):

[TouchingToolbar.zip](http://www.jonn8.com/dist/TouchingToolbar.zip)

If you really want the two items separated (but close together), set the style of the `NSSegmentedControl` in IB from `Rounded` to `Separated`:

[image]

Comment: That's it, thank you! I had to change the style to separated, and now it's perfect!